# Decrypt blowfish in php

Tags: javascript, php, mcrypt, blowfish

I'm using `blowfish.js` on my clientside. 
To encrypt on the clientside I use

```
var encryptedData = blowfish.encrypt(
    JSON.stringify(myData),  myEncryptionKey, {cipherMode: 0, outputType: 0}
);
```

That way `encryptedData` is Base64 encoded blowfish string. It is **OK**.

To decrypt on the clientside I use

```
var decryptedData = blowfish.decrypt(
     encryptedData , myEncryptionKey, {cipherMode: 0, outputType: 0}
);
```

So `decryptedData` equals to `JSON.stringify(myData)`. It is **OK**.

Then I send my `encryptedData` to the .php script that contains

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $myEncryptionKey, pack('H*',$data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

And when I try to print $data I'm getting something unreadable like

```
�Nv��Xd�̿�:q6��A����,!v��c�O¡1�%>��ҭ� {0�� �    ���g�u�����t�z3q$����T��/Ҧ.j-�/!���;�lS���Z�X
��&����{j�m�����F�`7��.......and so on
```

It **isnt OK**. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong on the server-side?

Comment: why ``pack('H*',$data)`` as you wrote ``data`` is a base64 encoded string, just ``base64_decode`` the data and pass it to the decrypt function

Comment: already tried without pack and still getting unreadable string

Comment: did you verify that after you ``base64`` decode the crypted string in php it is equal as on the client side?

Comment: yes, I compared and encryptedData in javascript equals to $_POST['data'] in php;

Comment: ins0 thank you. I forgot to make base64_decode before decrypting with blowfish. Argh as usual

Comment: should i post it as an answer?

Comment: @ins0 my advice: wait for OP's answers and eventually write it as an answer. Edit: Yes, do it (just saw OP's answer) and get it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you `pack('H*',$data)` as you wrote the data is a `base64` encoded string. Just `base64_decode` the data and pass it to the decrypt function.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$decryptedData = base64_decode($data);

$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $myEncryptionKey, $decryptedData, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```